# How to limit access for User and show specific menu parts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a component where through map I show all menu parts. How can I limit access(make it hidden) if user right for that part of menu is equal to 0?

```
  const Aside: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const[hasRight, setHasRight] = useState(false);

  useEffect( () => {
    getUserContext()
      .then((response) => {
        Object.keys(response.data.acl.rights).forEach(role => {
          const right = response.data.acl.rights[role];
          Object.keys(right).forEach(val => {
            right[val] > 0 ?
            setHasRight(true) :
            setHasRight(false);
          });
        });
        return response.data.acl;
      })
  }, [hasRight]);
  return (
    <div className="Aside">
      {hasRight?
        pages.map((page, index) => {
          return (
            <Link className="Aside__link" key={index} to={page.link}>
              <img className="Aside__link-image" src={page.img} alt="page__img" />
              <p>{page.title}</p>
            </Link>
          );
      }): null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this part I hide all menu if it does not have access. I need to check each menu item to see if there is access to it.

Comment: Where is the linking between your menus and rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user has many different rights for many different pages, so instead of creating `hasRight` as a `boolean` state, you need to store a keyed object showing whether they have rights for each page.  I'm assuming that if the user has multiple roles, they would have rights if any of their roles have rights.

```
type UserRights = Record<string, boolean>;

const [userRights, setUserRights] = useState<UserRights>({});
```

On the rendering side of things, we need to check whether they have the right for each page separately.  Instead of a ternary with `null`, we can use `array.filter()` to filter the pages before mapping them to JSX.

```
const canView = (page: PageConfig): boolean => {
  return userRights[page.acl];
}
```

```
<div className="Aside">
  {pages.filter(canView).map((page, index) => {
```

Prior to the response being loaded, there should be no viewable pages.

Inside our `useEffect`, we need to change the `setState` callbacks to support our keyed object format.  Instead of using `Object.keys` to iterate, we can use `Object.values` and `Object.entries` (provided that your tsconfig has lib: es2017 or newer).  I think this is correct, but you may need to tweak based on your response structure.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUserContext()
    .then((response: Response) => {
      Object.values(response.data.acl.rights).forEach(roleRights => {
        Object.entries(roleRights).forEach(([name, number]) => {
          setUserRights(existing => ({
            ...existing,
            [name]: existing[name] || number > 0 // true if true true for any role
          }))
        });
      });
    })
}, []);
```

The dependency for the useEffect should be the user id or something like that, otherwise use an empty array `[]` to run it once.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ymALBN)

Comment: could you explain why do we put [name]: existing[name] || number > 0 ? About number I understood

Comment: especially, what happens at this part:              
           Object.entries(roleRights).forEach(([name, number]) => {
            setUserRights(existing => ({
              ...existing,
              [name]: existing[name] || number > 0
            }))

Comment: why we used || ?

Comment: || means “or” so we are saying to set the permission to true if number > 0 or if it was already set to true.  Basically if they have multiple roles we don’t want to remove a permission that was already granted by a previous role.